# How to print alphabet pyramid starting with user input and descending?

Tags: java

This is homework and I need help understanding how and why.

I have tried to follow the numerous examples online, but they all hard code 'A' as the starting point, and I'm failing to reverse engineer the examples for my specific need.

I have to print a pyramid of letters starting with the user input (which also defines the height of the pyramid), assume the user typed E, like so:

```
E
ED
EDC
EDCB
EDCBA
```

My first problem is that I don't understand how to get the user input letter to be the starting point for each line.

This is Java and I can't use arrays or strings, only char and int.

Can someone please explain the logic in achieving this??

Here's my step one, this is what I know I can achieve:

```
intHeight = chrUserLetter - 'A' + 1; 
chrCurrentLetter = chrUserLetter;

for ( intRowIndex = 1; intRowIndex <= intHeight; intRowIndex += 1 )
{
    for ( intColumnIndex = 1; intColumnIndex <= intRowIndex; intColumnIndex += 1)
    {
        System.out.print( chrCurrentLetter );
        chrCurrentLetter -= 1;              
    }

    System.out.println();                           
}
```

And the output is:

```
E
DC
BA@
?>=<
;:987
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: Currently each time you execute your inner loop, which handles columns, you leave the `chrCurrentLetter` modified. This is a problem, as you obviously want the first letter of each line to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the line `chrCurrentLetter = chrUserLetter;`in the first for to reinitialize it

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char chrUserLetter='E';
        int intHeight = chrUserLetter - 'A' + 1;

        for ( int intRowIndex = 1; intRowIndex <= intHeight; intRowIndex += 1 )
        {
            char chrCurrentLetter = chrUserLetter;
            for (int intColumnIndex = 1; intColumnIndex <= intRowIndex; intColumnIndex += 1)
            {
                System.out.print( chrCurrentLetter );
                chrCurrentLetter -= 1;
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Omg.  I can't believe that was it!  I have spent so long trying different loops, if statements, etc.  As soon as it lets me accept your answer I will.   Could you expand on why the placement of that initializer made the difference?

Comment: In your original code you continue subtracting from the same variable in the each loop. All you need is just restart it for each inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the `chrCurrentLetter` variable in the next row. Move the assignment into the outer for loop:

```
intHeight = chrUserLetter - 'A' + 1; 

for ( intRowIndex = 1; intRowIndex <= intHeight; intRowIndex += 1 )
{
    chrCurrentLetter = chrUserLetter;
    for ( intColumnIndex = 1; intColumnIndex <= intRowIndex; intColumnIndex += 1)
    {
        System.out.print( chrCurrentLetter );
        chrCurrentLetter -= 1;              
    }

    System.out.println();                           
}
```

Explanation: If you assign the `chrCurrentLetter` only once, then for the first iteration it will be `E`. Then you decrement it once and it is `D` when you add the next iteration, and so on. By resetting it to `E` every time you get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you!  @StanislavL answered just a few seconds before you, but your solution was the same.  I appreciate the help!